# Angular make part of component unclickable

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

So I have this component that is a button, which when clicked, navigates to a certain route. However, I want to put a button inside this, which doesn't make it navigate and does something else.

How do I do this? It is the follow/unfollow button.

```
<button type="button" class="btn" (click)='navigate()' *ngIf="searchResult.username"><mat-card>
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>{{searchResult|null:['firstname']}} {{searchResult|null:['lastname']}}</mat-card-title>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content class="container">
    <div>{{searchResult|null: ['username']}}</div>
    <div>
      <!-- option to follow -->
  
      <div *ngIf="!result.followers.includes(this.selfUsername)" class="follow">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="onFollow()">
          Follow
        </button>
      </div>
  
      <!-- already following -->
  
      <div *ngIf="result.followers.includes(this.selfUsername)" class="follow">
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="onUnfollow()">
          Unfollow
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- dunno why these dont work -->
      <!-- <p *ngFor="let item of searchResult|null:['history']">{{item}}</p> -->
    </div>
    <div>
      <!-- <p *ngFor="let item of searchResult|null:['whishlist']">{{item}}</p> -->
    </div>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
</button>
```

Comment: Your main "button" doesnt have to be a button tag to accept clicks. So you can make it a mat card like mentioned in the answer below and still add (click) listner on it. That way you can add real buttons inside of that card that manage follow and unfollow

Answer (score 0):

Use button tags only when making interaction like calling functions that do something.

In your case you want to "hyperlink" somewhere (in this case it's a mat-card) and inside of if you want to place any buttons...let's say.

For navigation you should always use anchor tags like **<a  ... href="" or routerLink="">...content </ a>**

So, just change the root <button ...> to <a ...>.....

and that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

Like gsa.interactive said, you have to use a link for redirection.

With this logic you cannot have a clickable child button if it is located in a clickable parent element.  You can't position these child buttons above the parent with z-index.
A child's z-index is set to the same stacking index as its parent.

2 possibilities:

- you don't overlay the clickable link with the buttons.
- Either you overlay them in the following way:add position: relative to the parent with a z-index 0 and add position : absolute to the buttons with z-index 1 with a specific position